# can't connect phone to android studio adb

Tags: android-studio

I'm using a droid turbo 2 with android version 7. Earlier this evening I was working on an app in android studio. I downloaded the app to my phone for debugging many times so I know it worked at one time.  Now I can't get the app to download through the ADB. On the phone side, when the usb cord is connected I have an option of using the "usb to charge the device", "transfer files", "transfer photos", "use device as a MIDI", or "software installation". I need to pick software installation, but my phone immediately disappears from the connected devices part of select deployment target window in android studio when I do. If i recheck the box for usb to charge the device on the android then it will reappear on the select deployment target window in android studio.

USB debugging is enabled. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: first of all You say to me you use which operating system?

Comment: You have required to adb drive

Comment: You Must required Your usb plug is correctly connected with Your system and Your Phone Devloper mode Usb debuging is enabled then you can use easly You phone like emulater

Comment: As I said, I'm using Android version 7. I'm using ADB to download to my phone and as I said, USB debugging is enabled.